# Docker + connect to host (localdb)

Tags: docker, localdb

Is it possible to connect to SQL Server Express (localdb) from a container instance?

docker-compose sample connection string:

```yml
foo-api:
  image: foo-api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection=Server=host.docker.internal\\mssqllocaldb;Database=FooDB;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Id=foo;Password=Your_password123;        
    build:
      context: ../ms-foo/src/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "6004:6004"
```

Running the app @ localhost wtih this config works just fine:

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=FooDB;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Id=foo;Password=Your_password123;"
},
```

Is there some dns resolution I'm missing or does the instance need to be shared somehow?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15#shared-instances-of-localdb?

**Update**

Including the error message.

> {
> "error": "14 UNAVAILABLE: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)"}

Comment: what is the error of `foo-api`? do you get a timeout?

Answer (score 0):

You can reach the parent host on the container's network gateway.

Let's say your container address is `172.21.0.2`. In that case, you can most likely find the SQL server at `172.21.0.1` (and the correspondent listening port).

To find out the container's IP, you can try to jump into it and print its network config, i.e. `docker exec <container name> ip a`, but often `ip` and `ifconfig` commands are not installed, so I'd suggest looking at the bottom of `docker inspect <container name>`. Keys `IPAddress` and `Gateway` hold the discussed values.

You can then build your container with a custom `/etc/hosts`, or point it to DNS server that can resolve this, so you can use nice names instead of IP addresses.

Comment: Well, I'm pointing at the at the host with `host.docker.internal`.

Comment: I'm not sure `host.docker.internal` is a valid/resolvable hostname, for Linux containers at least, but you can try it by jumping into the container and use it, see if it resolves -> `docker exec -it <container name> bash` and take it from there.

Comment: It works just fine, used it in multiple scenarios when connection to an API on the host machine.

Comment: Interesting. I think I may be missing some details then, to me, on alpine or debian containers, I get `host.docker.internal: Name or service not known`. Do you get the same error when using the gateway? (if you don't use dedicated network, then the default gateway IP is most likely `172.17.0.1`)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your error related to the environment variable defined on your docker-compose file , the second variable must be like that:

```sh
variable_name="value2"
```

So for your case must be like that:

```sh
DB_CONNECTION_STRING="ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"
DB_SERVER="host.docker.internal\\mssqllocaldb"
DB_NAME="FooDB"
DB_MultipleActiveResultSets=true
DB_USER_ID="foo"
DB_PASSWORD="Your_password123"
```

after that you can use this env variables to define your connection:

```sh
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=FooDB;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Id=foo;Password=Your_password123;"
},
```

I hope that can help you to resolve your issue.